# Finding the cell position (row,column) by using variable

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have an Excel sheet having one column as date as below :

[image]

My Job is to find to the position (cell,column) for a today's date

Script I am using :

```
Sub MacroExample()    
 Dim a As Variant   
 Dim column_Position As Variant  
 Dim row_Position As Variant   
 a = Format(Date - 1, "MM\/dd\/yyyy")   
 'MsgBox "The Value of a : " & a    
 Dim oRange          As Range   
 Set oRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z10000").Find(a, lookat:=xlPart)

 'MsgBox oRange.Address    
 MsgBox column_Position   
 MsgBox row_Position    
End Sub
```

My output should be:

```
column_Position = 5 
row_Position = 1
```

Comment: Kindly click "enter image description here" to preview the sample sheet

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are asking, I hope this helps. This code should find the first occurrence of today's date in a specified search range.

```
Sub testDate()

Dim a As Variant
Dim column_Position As Variant
Dim row_Position As Variant

'get today's date, formatted m/d/yyyy
a = Format(Date, "m/d/yyyy")

Dim oRange As range
Dim myCell As range

'set a range to look through
Set oRange = Worksheets(1).range("A1:Z10000")

'check each cell value if it contains today's date. If so, capture the column and row and
'exit the loop.
For Each myCell In oRange

    If InStr(1, myCell.Value, a) Then
        column_Position = myCell.column
        row_Position = myCell.Row
        Exit For
    End If
Next myCell

'display the column and row position, if wanted.
MsgBox "Column Position is " & column_Position & vbNewLine & "Row Position is " & row_Position

End Sub
```

[Code Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAwcr.jpg)

I cannot say how efficient this is, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you look for a `String` within some larger string:

```
Sub MacroExample()
    Dim a As String

    a = Format(Date - 1, "MM/dd/yyyy")
    MsgBox "The Value of a : " & a
    Dim oRange As Range
    Set oRange = Sheets(1).Range("A1:Z10000").Find(what:=a, lookat:=xlPart)
    MsgBox oRange.Column
    MsgBox oRange.Row
End Sub
```

[image]

***Note:***

The date includes the desired leading zeros.